# Read file in CSV helper

Tags: csvhelper

Trying to read a file where the data is not separated by commas `,` but using  quotation marks: `"`

For example:

`"num"   "date"  "callsite"  "level" "thread"`

Can this be done?

`csvhelper` gives an exception that the header cannot be found.

Comment: Is the data separated by tabs or spaces?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is separated by tabs, then you can set `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";`

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("\"num\"\t\"date\"\t\"callsite\"\t\"level\"\t\"thread\"");
            writer.WriteLine("\"1\"\t\"1/1/2019\"\t\"callsite1\"\t\"high\"\t\"20\"");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";

            var results = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string callsite { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string thread { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's looks like I have TAB inserted between of the headers, setting \t as Delimiter resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to help.  I changed my answer to reflect a tab delimited file.